# adding second to my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello how can I add a second portion to my javascript. Here is the code:

```
var $pagerT = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
var $pagerB = $('<div class="pager"></div>');
for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
    $('<span class="page-number"></span>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
        newPage: page
    }, function(event) {
        currentPage = event.data['newPage'];
        $table.trigger('repaginate');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    }).appendTo($pagerT).addClass('clickable');                 
}
```

Basically I want to add the same class that was added to $pagerT to $pagerB. Here is the code:

```
}).appendTo($pagerT, $pagerB).addClass('clickable');
```

Any subjections on how I can process it?

Comment: Is there an `.appendTo($pagerT) and .appendTo($pagerB);`

Comment: Are you also trying to insert the `<span class="page-number">...` etc. that you're appending to $pagerT into $pagerB, as your second code sample suggests?

Comment: @user3618837 Are you trying to append the `<span>` to both `<div>`s? If so, you'll have to create a 2nd `<span>` for the 2nd `<div>`. Any subsequent `.appendTo()`s will simply move the 1 `<span>`.

Comment: No, there's no such `and`. If you try to do `.appendTo($pagerT).appendTo($pagerB)`, it will move the `<span>` into $pagerT and then remove it into $pagerB. See http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: You said that you want to "add the same class that was added to $pagerT to $pagerB", but in the code you showed, no class was added to $pagerT. Instead, the class was added to the **span** that was appended to $pagerT. `appendTo()` returns the inserted element(s) (http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$pagerT.add($pagerB).addClass('clickable');
```

Comment: This looks like it will add the 'clickable' class to $pagerB and to the `<span class="page-number">` that's being appended to $pagerT, not to $pagerT itself.

Comment: Good call @LarsH, didn't notice the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say

```
var $pagers = $pagerT.add($pagerB);

...
}).appendTo($pagers);
$pagers.addClass('clickable');
```

The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) say that the argument to `appendTo()` can be an array of elements, and in that case, "cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target after the first".

(However I'm not sure if `$pagerT.add($pagerB)` creates an array (the doc says it creates a set); or more to the point, whether this value is acceptable as an argument to appendTo(). Testing this is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Or if you value brevity over maintainability,

```
...
}).appendTo($pagers.addClass('clickable'));
```

That's assuming that you want to add the `<span>` to both $pagerT and $pagerB (which you didn't say, but your second code example suggests) and add the 'clickable' class to both (which you said but which conflicts with your original code).